# how to align Button to the right of the window

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to align the login button to the Top right of the page.

I have Logo on left corner of the page and need to keep Login button to top right. when I am trying to do with padding-left the alignment is changing when I see in another screen size.

I am building this in React JS

```html
   <Box >
  <Grid className="custom-home__header" >
    <Box padding={{ vertical: "s" }}>
      <Grid>
        <Box>
          <img
            className="photo"
            src={image}
            alt=" Logo"
          />
        </Box>
      </Grid>

    </Box>

    <Box className="style" padding={{ vertical: "m" }} >
      <Grid
        className="custom-home__header" >
        <Box className="style" >
          <Button className="style"
            variant="primary"
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              const {
                REACT_APP_AUTH_URL,
                REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
              } = process.env;
              const authUrl = new URL(
                `${REACT_APP_AUTH_URL}/login` || ""
              );
              authUrl.searchParams.append("response_type", "token");
              const stateValue = uuidv4();
              storeAccessTokenState(stateValue);
              authUrl.searchParams.append("state", stateValue);
              authUrl.searchParams.append(
                "client_id",
                REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID || ""
              );
              authUrl.searchParams.append(
                "scope",
                "profile openid"
              );
              authUrl.searchParams.append(
                "redirect_uri",
                encodeURI(`${window.location.href}callback`)
              );
              window.location.href = authUrl.href;
            }}
          >
            Login
          </Button>

        </Box>
```

**CSS :**

```css
.custom-home__header {
  background-color: $color-background-home-header;
}

.login{
padding-left: 620px;
}
```

How can I do this?
[login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNQj7.png)

please see [the screen shot login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNQj7.png), I need to align login button to right corner

Comment: Hi, Monica. Welcome to SO. It will be very helpful if you provide your code as well, that way we'll know where exactly to help you. There are several ways of aligning a button to any direction.

Comment: Hi Pelicer, I have edited the post with the code

Comment: How about float right, or use flex box. Are you a back end developer diving into front end? Just wondering how come you working in React if you don't know basic html-css.

Comment: @user31782 I have tried float right, flexbox and also padding. But it didn't work. When I use padding the alignment is changing for different screens.Yes, I am not frontend developer and trying my ways.

Comment: What about your style sheet? I see you applying some but I see no CSS. Can you edit the question?

Comment: @Pelicer I have added the css content in the question

Comment: Perhaps show your rendered HTML so we can help better here with some nice CSS - since that is what the CSS will actually target here.

Comment: @Mark schultheiss I have already attached the rendered page in the screenshot. Please click login screen[1]

Comment: Not a picture, please perhaps post the actual HTML that is rendered so you have a complete question.

Comment: Note that it is very unorthodox to put that much code into an inline event handler. Typically one would create a function that encapsulates that logic, then set the event handler to a reference to that function. Also, that "CSS" looks an awful lot like SCSS. Please include the CSS that is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Update: Now that you've posted your CSS you can use `position` to move the button to the top right

```css
.login{
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
}
```

Depending upon where you'd like to place you can set the `position` of the button i.e:

Place button on top right relative to the container `position: absolute;`

Or on top right fixed to the top and right relative to the window `position: fixed;`.

`top: 0px;` sets your element to the top

`right: 0px;` sets your element to the right

Setting it on top right of the page will keep it in a fixed position regardless of your page scroll.

```css
.topRightOfContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

.FixedOntopRightOfPage {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #999900;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="FixedOntopRightOfPage">Button Fixed on Top Right of Page</button>
<div>
  A Container
</div>
<div>
  Another Container
  <button class="topRightOfContainer">Button on Top Right of Container</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked for me. I have used FixedOntopRightOfPage and it worked!

Comment: If the answer helped then mark it as accepted to help other dev who stumble upon it :)

Comment: I have applied the solution which you have mentioned but when I scroll the page down the login button is also scrolling down.

Comment: Use `position: absolute;` to fix it to the right of the container as mentioned in the class `topRightOfContainer`. Run the Code Snippet and scroll down to see. Make sure your container width is 100% in order for the button to move to the right.

Comment: I have a collapsible navigation bar at left (beside the logo) when I keep the position :absolute and the set the left alignment it seems ok, but when I expand the collapsible window the button also moves to the right and it is going out of the box.